# Accessing container-side Postgres database via container-side Node.js web app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I have a Dockerfile for a Node.js app that overall looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https \
        build-essential \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
        libssl-dev \
        wget \
        postgresql-10 postgresql-client-10 postgresql-contrib-10

USER postgres
RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER warbler WITH SUPERUSER;" &&\
    createdb -O warbler warbler_store

# ... node setup stuff ...
# ...
# ...

RUN psql -U warbler -d warbler_store -f db_v1.sql

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

With this though I get the following error message:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've looked around online a bit and the majority of solutions I've found seem to say that docker is trying to connect to the *host* postgres instance, among other questions that have to do with docker containers whose primary purpose is to run PostgreSQL. Is this accurate, and if so is it still possible to run a container-side PostgreSQL instance that's accessible by the primary application?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's not good practice to have your database in the same Docker container as your web app. I changed my container structure by just using the `postgresql:10` image in another container and having the web app communicate with it via `docker-compose`. `docker-compose` allows one to define services and Docker's internal DNS will allow them to communicate with each other

This is what the `docker-compose.yaml` looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
        - .:/app
        links:
        - db

    db:
        image: postgres:10
        environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=warbler
        - POSTGRES_DB=warbler_store
        volumes:
        - ./db_v1.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_v1.sql
        - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
    dbdata:
```

In this case, in the Dockerfile for `web`, I set the necessary environment variables so Node connects to the database running at `postgresql://db:5432/warbler_store`. `db` resolves via DNS to the IP address of the container running the `db` service, which is the `postgres` image container.